# How to remove duplication in this array/tree generating function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Here we have the following code.

```js
let i = 1
while (i <= 256) {
  log(i)
  i++
}

function shape(n) {
  let p = greatestPowerOf2(n);
  if (p >= n) {
    // The only cases where there are no subarrays
    return [n];
  }

  // Try with one subarray
  for (let sub = 2; sub < n && sub <= 256; sub *= 2) {
    let top = n - sub + 1;
    p = greatestPowerOf2(top);
    if (p >= top) {
      return [p - 1, sub];
    }
  }

  // Try with two subarrays
  for (let sub1 = 2; sub1 < n && sub1 <= 256; sub1 *= 2) {
    for (let sub2 = 2; sub2 <= sub1; sub2 *= 2) {
      let top = n - sub1 - sub2 + 2;
      if (top < 0) break;
      p = greatestPowerOf2(top);
      if (p >= top) {
        return [p - 2, sub1, sub2];
      }
    }
  }

  // Try with three subarrays
  for (let sub1 = 2; sub1 < n && sub1 <= 256; sub1 *= 2) {
    for (let sub2 = 2; sub2 <= sub1; sub2 *= 2) {
      for (let sub3 = 2; sub3 <= sub2; sub3 *= 2) {
        let top = n - sub1 - sub2 - sub3 + 3;
        if (top < 0) break;
        p = greatestPowerOf2(top);
        if (p >= top) {
          return [p - 3, sub1, sub2, sub3];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Try with four subarrays
  for (let sub1 = 2; sub1 < n && sub1 <= 256; sub1 *= 2) {
    for (let sub2 = 2; sub2 <= sub1; sub2 *= 2) {
      for (let sub3 = 2; sub3 <= sub2; sub3 *= 2) {
        for (let sub4 = 2; sub4 <= sub3; sub4 *= 2) {
          let top = n - sub1 - sub2 - sub3 - sub4 + 4;
          if (top < 0) break;
          p = greatestPowerOf2(top);
          if (p >= top) {
            return [p - 4, sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Try with five subarrays
  for (let sub1 = 2; sub1 < n && sub1 <= 256; sub1 *= 2) {
    for (let sub2 = 2; sub2 <= sub1; sub2 *= 2) {
      for (let sub3 = 2; sub3 <= sub2; sub3 *= 2) {
        for (let sub4 = 2; sub4 <= sub3; sub4 *= 2) {
          for (let sub5 = 2; sub5 <= sub4; sub5 *= 2) {
            let top = n - sub1 - sub2 - sub3 - sub4 - sub5 + 5;
            if (top < 0) break;
            p = greatestPowerOf2(top);
            if (p >= top) {
              return [p - 5, sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Try with 6 subarrays
  for (let sub1 = 2; sub1 < n && sub1 <= 256; sub1 *= 2) {
    for (let sub2 = 2; sub2 <= sub1; sub2 *= 2) {
      for (let sub3 = 2; sub3 <= sub2; sub3 *= 2) {
        for (let sub4 = 2; sub4 <= sub3; sub4 *= 2) {
          for (let sub5 = 2; sub5 <= sub4; sub5 *= 2) {
            for (let sub6 = 2; sub6 <= sub5; sub6 *= 2) {
              let top = n - sub1 - sub2 - sub3 - sub4 - sub5 - sub6 + 6;
              if (top < 0) break;
              p = greatestPowerOf2(top);
              if (p >= top) {
                return [p - 6, sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5, sub6];
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Try with 7 subarrays
  for (let sub1 = 2; sub1 < n && sub1 <= 256; sub1 *= 2) {
    for (let sub2 = 2; sub2 <= sub1; sub2 *= 2) {
      for (let sub3 = 2; sub3 <= sub2; sub3 *= 2) {
        for (let sub4 = 2; sub4 <= sub3; sub4 *= 2) {
          for (let sub5 = 2; sub5 <= sub4; sub5 *= 2) {
            for (let sub6 = 2; sub6 <= sub5; sub6 *= 2) {
              for (let sub7 = 2; sub7 <= sub6; sub7 *= 2) {
                let top = n - sub1 - sub2 - sub3 - sub4 - sub5 - sub6 - sub7 + 7;
                if (top < 0) break;
                p = greatestPowerOf2(top);
                if (p >= top) {
                  return [p - 7, sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5, sub6, sub7];
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  throw new Error(n)
}

function greatestPowerOf2(n) {
  return n >= 256 ? 256 : n >= 128 ? 128 : n >= 64 ? 64 : n >= 32 ? 32 : n >= 16 ? 16 : n >= 8 ? 8 : n >= 4 ? 4 : n >= 2 ? 2 : 1;
}

function log(n) {
  console.log(`${n} => ${JSON.stringify(shape(n))}`)
}
```

It consists of a `shape` function which takes a number from 1 to 256, and outputs an array following [this](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/2c9f31c560d41dbe3119983b1eeeb728) pattern (here is a snippet):

```
base-1
  a

base-2
  a
  b

base-3
  a
  tree
    b
    c

base-4
  a
  b
  c
  d

base-5
  a
  b
  c
  tree
    d
    e

base-6
  a
  b
  tree
    c
    d
  tree
    e
    f

base-7
  a
  b
  tree
    c
    d
    e
    f
  tree
    g
```

Basically, it says the "shape" of the tree that should be produced. For example, on `log(12)` it outputs `[6,4,2]`. That means there should be 6 top-level elements, followed by nested 2 elements (starting from the top), followed by nested 2 elements (starting from the top again). This `shape` function will always return an array where every level of the array has a power of 2 number of elements (6 + 2 children is 8 a power of 2, 2 is power of 2, and 2 is a power of 2).

The question is, how can you remove the duplication of the `shape` function, where it has loops for 2, 3, or 4 nested arrays? How can you remove those "cases" and make it into a generic loop of some sort that tries 2, then tries 3, then tries 4, without a switch statement or any sort of duplication?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Comment: @Lance Can you explain why 12 => [6,4,2] but not [4,2,2,2,2] I didn't quite catch the idea. But I have a feeling that maybe there is no need for so many cycles, everything can be solved by calculation.

Comment: @DaniilLoban because I think it tries to fill the top-level with as many nodes as it can, to keep the traversal to a minimum. Then it fills the nested nodes with whatever else. It would look like this for example: `[a, b, c, d, e, f, [g, h, i, j], [k, l]]`. See [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/274137/how-to-optimize-push-and-pop-in-this-tree-list-algorithm) for all the possible shapes (at the bottom).

Comment: @Lance there is an option how to improve this code by almost getting rid of embedded loops, but its performance drops by 2.5 times on average, so I do not know if it is worth publishing, it only has flexibility.